# Drawing a regression line in C#

Tags: c#, plot, zedgraph, loglog

The Python code gives me the following plot:

[image]

C# code gives me the following plot:

[image]

It is obvious that Python code is more accurate as the scales of the lines are preserved and the regression line goes through more points.

What is wrong with my C# code?

---

.

**Python code**

```
# Fit2.py
import numpy as np

def ReadDataFromFile(data_file_path):
    """
    Reads data from a file assuming two columns of numbers, separated by whitespace.
    Returns two lists, one for x-values and one for y-values.
    """
    with open(data_file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    x_values = []
    y_values = []

    for line in lines:
        parts = line.strip().split()
        if len(parts) == 2:
            x_values.append(float(parts[0]))
            y_values.append(float(parts[1]))

    return x_values, y_values

def CreateRegressionLine(x_values, y_values):
    """
    Creates a regression line based on log-log transformed data.
    Returns two lists containing the log-space points of the regression line.
    """
    log_x_values = np.log(x_values)
    log_y_values = np.log(y_values)

    # Fit the regression using np.polyfit for a first degree polynomial, which is a linear fit
    slope, intercept = np.polyfit(log_x_values, log_y_values, 1)

    # Create the regression line in log space
    regression_log_y_values = slope * log_x_values + intercept

    # Convert the regression line back to linear space
    regression_y_values = np.exp(regression_log_y_values)

    return x_values, regression_y_values.tolist()
```

.

**C# code**

```
public static class Fit2
    {
        public static Tuple<List<double>, List<double>> ReadDataFromFile(string filePath)
        {
            var xList = new List<double>();
            var yList = new List<double>();

            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("#")) continue; // Skip the comment lines

                var parts = line.Split('\t');
                if (parts.Length == 2)
                {
                    if (double.TryParse(parts[0], out var x) && double.TryParse(parts[1], out var y))
                    {
                        xList.Add(x);
                        yList.Add(y);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Tuple.Create(xList, yList);
        }

        public static Tuple<double, double> CalculateLinearRegressionCoefficients(double[] xValues, double[] yValues)
        {
            if (xValues.Length != yValues.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Input arrays must have the same length.");
            }

            var (a, b) = SimpleRegression.Fit(xValues, yValues);
            return Tuple.Create(a, b);
        }

        public static Tuple<List<double>, List<double>> CreateRegressionLine(List<double> xList, List<double> yList)
        {
            var xValues = xList.ToArray();
            var yValues = yList.ToArray();
            var coefficients = CalculateLinearRegressionCoefficients(xValues, yValues);

            var xVals = new List<double> { xValues.First(), xValues.Last() };
            var yVals = xVals.Select(x => coefficients.Item1 + coefficients.Item2 * x).ToList();

            return Tuple.Create(xVals, yVals);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot represent zero in a logarithmic scale. This also means that the values must be either all positive or all negative.

Comment: Make the new line longer.  It is not showing on a Log plot but is showing a linear plot.  The new line is very small on the log plot.